# GLSL Setting Texture Unit Uniform Problems

Tags: opengl, graphics, shader, opentk

**Edit:**
I changed GLTextureUnitID from a uint to an int, and it caused the error to stop appearing, but instead of the texture, a black square renders. When I comment out the call to SetTexture it still renders fine even though I never set that uniform before that line.

**Edit2:**
It appears GLTextureUnitID has a value of 1, while the texture that is being set has an ID of 0.

**Edit3:**
Changing the SetTexture function to have the following seems to have solved the problem, but it feels like a bit of a dirty solution.

```
GL.BindTexture(TextureTarget.Texture2D, (int)texture.GLTextureUnitID);
GL.Uniform1(GLTextureUnitLocation, 0);
```

**Original Question:**
I started adding support for texture files to my project but whenever I call GL.Uniform1 for my textured shader program, I get an "InvalidOperation" error. Ever stranger, when I comment out the call to the function that causes the error, the texture still gets rendered.

The RenderGUI function in which the quad with a texture is being rendered is:

```
    public override void RenderGUI()
    {
        // Translate Matrix to Position of GUI Element
        Matrices.Translate(SetMatrixParam.ModelViewMatrix, Position.X, Position.Y, 0);

        // Bind Shaders and Send Matrices
        Shader.Bind();
        Shader.SendMatrices();

        // Set Texture Information
        Shader.SetTexture(Texture); // <- This causes the error, it's just a call to Uniform1 using a property from the texture object, if commented out the error doesn't appear.
        Shader.SetTextureColor(Color4.White);

        GL.Begin(BeginMode.Triangles);

        // Render Quad
        Vector3 topLeft = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        Vector3 bottomLeft = new Vector3(0, Size.Y, 0);
        Vector3 topRight = new Vector3(Size.X, 0, 0);
        Vector3 bottomRight = new Vector3(Size.X, Size.Y, 0);

        Shader.SetTextureCoord(0, 0); GL.Vertex3(topLeft); // Top Left
        Shader.SetTextureCoord(0, 1); GL.Vertex3(bottomLeft); // Bottom Left
        Shader.SetTextureCoord(1, 1); GL.Vertex3(bottomRight); // Bottom Right

        Shader.SetTextureCoord(0, 0); GL.Vertex3(topLeft); // Top Left
        Shader.SetTextureCoord(1, 1); GL.Vertex3(bottomRight); // Bottom Right
        Shader.SetTextureCoord(1, 0); GL.Vertex3(topRight); // Top Right

        GL.End();
    }
```

And the function that's being called that's causing an error to appear:

```
    public void SetTexture(Texture2D texture)
    {
        if (texture.GLTextureUnitID == null)
            throw new ArgumentException();

        GL.Uniform1(GLTextureUnitLocation, (uint)texture.GLTextureUnitID);
    }
```

[This can also be found at the github for this project.](https://github.com/LaylConway/TrenchWars/blob/master/EngineClient/GUI/Elements/GUITextureRenderer.cs) along with the [Texture2D class](https://github.com/LaylConway/TrenchWars/blob/master/EngineClient/Graphics/Textures/Texture2D.cs) and the [vertex](https://github.com/LaylConway/TrenchWars/blob/master/EngineClient/Graphics/Shaders/Texture2DVertex.glvs) and [fragment](https://github.com/LaylConway/TrenchWars/blob/master/EngineClient/Graphics/Shaders/Texture2DFragment.glfs) shader being used and the [class handling the shader program that uses those shaders](https://github.com/LaylConway/TrenchWars/blob/master/EngineClient/Graphics/ShaderPrograms/Texture2DShaderProgram.cs).

Answer (score 2):

Where is the code with the error?

From http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glUniform.xml there is a list of many reasons why glUniform1 would return an GL_INVALID_OPERATION.  I'd suggest just going through each one and confirming for yourself that it either applies or does not apply.

Here's the list:

> Errors
>
> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if there is no current program
>   object.
>
> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if the size of the uniform variable
>   declared in the shader does not match the size indicated by the
>   glUniform command.
>
> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if one of the signed or unsigned
>   integer variants of this function is used to load a uniform variable
>   of type float, vec2, vec3, vec4, or an array of these, or if one of
>   the floating-point variants of this function is used to load a uniform
>   variable of type int, ivec2, ivec3, ivec4, unsigned int, uvec2, uvec3,
>   uvec4, or an array of these.
>
> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if one of the signed integer
>   variants of this function is used to load a uniform variable of type
>   unsigned int, uvec2, uvec3, uvec4, or an array of these.
>
> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if one of the unsigned integer
>   variants of this function is used to load a uniform variable of type
>   int, ivec2, ivec3, ivec4, or an array of these.
>
> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if location is an invalid uniform
>   location for the current program object and location is not equal to
>   -1.
>
> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if count is greater than 1 and the
>   indicated uniform variable is not an array variable.
>
> GL_INVALID_OPERATION is generated if a sampler is loaded using a
>   command other than glUniform1i and glUniform1iv.

Comment: I added a comment in the code snippet where the error happens, reading over the list and trying things out now.

Comment: New problem came up, added additional data.

Answer (score 1):

In order to bind a texture to a program's uniform slot, you will need:

1. the gl-name of the texture which is returned from glGenTextures
2. the uniform location returned from glGetUniformLocation
3. a texture unit to bind the texture (it should be decided by your
   system; usually depending on how many textures are needed to bind to the shader)

In your texture class, I think you have mixed up the texture-unit and the gl-name.

And the followings is the pseudo code for texture binding

```
Int32 texunit = 0; // assume your shader only have 1 texture-type uniform
Shader.Bind();
GL.Uniform1( Shader.GetUniformLocation( "uniformName" ), texunit );
GL.ActiveTexture( texunit );
GL.BindTexture( TextureTarget.Texture2D, (int)tex.GLTextureUnitID ); // I recommend renaming tex.GLTextureUnitID to tex.GLName
```

Hope this helps